# How can I use a picture as font color in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I want to use a picture as font-color,

either with one picture set as background/font-color (is that even possible?)

or I have an ImageView in the background, on it my Label with backgroundcolor set as white (#FFFFFF) and I want to see through the Label in the shape of the text (setting the font-color to transparent doesn't work because then there is the background-color of the Label in the way...)

How can I realize this?

Thanks in advance and I hope it is understandable...

Paul

Comment: you can use digital meter to get the RGB of any image.

Comment: Wow, that's a cool idea.

Comment: @Hemant but I don't want to simply have the color of the background, but the image itself... but thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this programically:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name"];
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorwithPatternOfImage:image];
object.backgroundColor = color;
```

Or in Interface Builder simply add UIImageView to the View and set image.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think of such fast answers. Thank you very much. btw: It's [UIColor colorwithPatternImage:image]; and taking it as object.textColor helped me out, but I didn't even know these APIs existed...